# Ошибка list index out of range при парсинге сайта

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Имеется данный код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
r = requests.get('https://www.pointercrate.com/demonlist/')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
for el in html.select('.panel'):
    title = el.select('.text-align > a')
    print(title[0].text)
```

По идее код должен возвратить список топа, но в итоге получаю ошибку list index out of range

Comment: В чем вопрос? Очевидно, что в title ничего нет.

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему возвращается ошибка. Простите если что-то не так, я новичок

Comment: Я же написал: потому что в title ничего нет.

Comment: Странно... Кстати писал по инструкции Хауди Хо про парсинг сайтов на python

Comment: @ДенисСапфиров, ошибка из-за того, что искомый элемент не найден. Скорее всего структура этой страницы поменялась, а инструкция нет.

Comment: Или сайт просто банит парсеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код, который выполняет данную задачу:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.pointercrate.com/demonlist/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll('div', class_='leftlined pad')
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Или, используя `select`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.pointercrate.com/demonlist/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.select('div.leftlined.pad')
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Comment: Так почему тогда не парсить через html.parser? lxml это плюс одна зависимость, да и к тому на windows он очень проблемный)

Comment: @dhvcc изменил код

Comment: благодарю! спасибо огромное